# Where's the code that bitcoin core uses to generate private keys

Tags: private-key, source-code

I was looking through the repository but theres just too many folders to go through

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Wheres the code bitcoin core uses to generate private keys?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with code to generate private keys?

Comment: I want to replicate that in a small program Im making

Comment: Which language are you writing your 'program' in?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to find out:

BIP32 says:

> ### Master key generation
>
> The total number of possible extended keypairs
> is almost 2512, but the produced keys are only 256 bits long, and
> offer about half of that in terms of security. Therefore, master keys
> are not generated directly, but instead from a potentially short seed
> value.
>
> - Generate a seed byte sequence S of a chosen length (between 128 and
>   512 bits; 256 bits is advised) from a (P)RNG.
> - **Calculate I = HMAC-SHA512(Key = "Bitcoin seed", Data = S)**
> - Split I into two 32-byte sequences, IL and IR.
> - Use parse256(IL) as master secret key, and IR as master chain code.
>
> In case parse256(IL) is 0 or parse256(IL) ≥ n, the master key is invalid.

(my emphasis)

So we need to find references to HMAC-SHA512 (or variations):

```
C:> findstr /S  "HMAC.SHA512" *.cpp *.h
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.cpp:CHMAC_SHA512::CHMAC_SHA512(const unsigned char* key, size_t keylen)
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.cpp:void CHMAC_SHA512::Finalize(unsigned char hash[OUTPUT_SIZE])
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.h:#ifndef BITCOIN_CRYPTO_HMAC_SHA512_H
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.h:#define BITCOIN_CRYPTO_HMAC_SHA512_H
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.h:class CHMAC_SHA512
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.h:    CHMAC_SHA512(const unsigned char* key, size_t keylen);
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.h:    CHMAC_SHA512& Write(const unsigned char* data, size_t len)
bitcoin-master\src\crypto\hmac_sha512.h:#endif // BITCOIN_CRYPTO_HMAC_SHA512_H
bitcoin-master\src\hash.cpp:    CHMAC_SHA512(chainCode.begin(), chainCode.size()).Write(&header, 1).Write(data, 32).Write(num, 4).Finalize(output);
bitcoin-master\src\key.cpp:    CHMAC_SHA512{hashkey, sizeof(hashkey)}.Write(seed.data(), seed.size()).Finalize(vout.data());
bitcoin-master\src\test\crypto_tests.cpp:    TestVector(CHMAC_SHA512(key.data(), key.size()), ParseHex(hexin), ParseHex(hexout));
bitcoin-master\src\test\fuzz\crypto.cpp:    CHMAC_SHA512 hmac_sha512{data.data(), data.size()};
bitcoin-master\src\test\fuzz\crypto.cpp:                        data.resize(CHMAC_SHA512::OUTPUT_SIZE);
```

So `key.cpp` seems to be calling (rather than defining) HMAC_SHA512 ...

I stopped there but you could make a note of the name of the method in `key.cpp` that calls HMAC_SHA512 and repeat the search for calls to *that* method until you find code whose method names, variable names and comments suggest you have reached the right place.

Obviously, on Linux  instead of `findstr /S` you'll use `grep -r` .

---

Note that using any of this code is likely to be subject to the licence terms and conditions. These are set out in the file named COPYING - it is the MIT licence.